# Loading custom class in laravel without dump autoload

Tags: php, laravel-4, autoload

I have directory `/libraries/` under `/app/`. Libraries is suppose to hold all custom files and classes. I'm putted new file there but it doesn't work because I need to `dump-autoload`.. The problem is that I can't do this. No access to terminal etc..

I have this in `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/libraries",          // <<----- this one
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Another file which is in libraries from the very beginning is working just fine.

My question is how can I load this new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something which I recently tried and it's worked for me. Navigate to `vendor/composer/`. Since you've said that you have one php file in libraries and it's working this means you will have it in followed files and you can copy/paste the lines and change with your files.

First open file `autoload_classmap.php` and add at the bottom of the array

```
'yourfile' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/yourfile.php',
```

Second open file `autoload_static.php` and at the bottom add your file again

```
public static $classMap = array (
    ...
    'yourfile' => __DIR__.  '/../..' . '/app/libraries/yourfile.php',
```

Save both files and reload. In my case this loaded the files without need of auto-dump.